# Linked List Implementation error in C

Tags: c, linked-list

First of all sorry if my question is a little bit silly but it is really important to learn from these stupid mistakes specially when I'm learning something new like Linked List in C programming language which is why I'm here, I'm implementing a simple linked list using a seperate function that insert a node(element) in the start of list but This problem always happens, I'll show you the code and tell me if I'm doing something wrong and thanx alot:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct element{
    int nb;
    struct element *next;
}e;
e Insert(e hd,int x){
    e *temp = (e*)malloc(sizeof(e));
    temp->nb=x;
    temp->next = hd; /*It shows that the error is here, all what im doing here is that im letting the temp element points to whichever the head elements in pointing at so it can take it place as the first element)*/
    return temp; /*here I'm returning the @ of temp to the head node*/
}
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    e *head=NULL;
    head=Insert(head,5);
    system("PAUSE");    
    return 0;
}
```

and what the error says is : incompatible types in assignment

Comment: Don't you get a warning, calling `Insert(e, int)` as `Insert(e*,int)`? (`head` is an `e *`)?

Comment: Also your `Insert()` method returns an `e *`, not an `e` as you declared.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Insert()` should pass `e*` in and returns `e*`.

```
e* Insert(e* hd,int x){
    e *temp = malloc(sizeof(e));
    temp->nb=x;
    temp->next = hd;
    return temp;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Insert should be taking `e* hd` as argument and returning `e*`. The method should be:

`e* Insert(e* hd,int x){...}`